# How to add fixed bar displaying today's date below navigation bar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a uitableview with a tabbar and a navigation bar. Just below the navigation bar, I want another fixed bar, sticking to the navigation bar even while scrolling through the table, which will display today's date. I know that the displaying the date involves NSDateFrmatter and such, so converting NSDates is not the issue. The issue is bar itself. How can I add such a fixed bar, and add a title (which will be the dates) to it?

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of ways you could achieve this, but here's what I'd do: first, create a `UIViewController` subclass, and add a `UIToolbar` instance to the controller's view with a frame of `CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 320.f, 44.f)`. Then, create a `UITableView` instance, and also add it to the view with a frame of `CGRectMake(0.f, 44.f, 320.f, self.view.frame.size.height - 44.f)`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using UITableViewController you will have to subclass UIViewController and put a UIView with you date at the top and then the tableview below it. And set it up as the delegate and data source for the table in the header file and the outlets in Interface Builder.

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

The only other thing that UITableViewController provides for you that you may need to implement yourself is it will automatically clear the table’s current selection when it receives a viewWillAppear: message.